# how to combine two numeric fields?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How to combine two int columns into one.

```
My table1 is as follows:
name   adress1  adress2
hhh    1        2
www    2        3
```

I want result as follows:

```
name columnz
hhh  12
www  23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, CAST(ADRESS1 AS VARCHAR(20)) + CAST(ADRESS2 AS VARCHAR(20)) AS columnz from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

In the upcoming SQL-server you can do:

> SELECT name, concat(address1,address2) as columnz 
>       FROM table1

However SQL-server does not allow concat yet, so you'll have the use the '+' operator and a cast.

```
SELECT 
  name
  ,CAST(address1 AS char)+CAST(address2 AS char) as columnz
FROM table1
```

SQL is not that troublesome about the difference between strings and numbers.

Another option is:

```
SELECT name, (address1*10+address2) as columnz 
FROM table1
```

Comment: it says concat not recognized.

Comment: No second query is not going to work because there are chances that address2 has value as 21, 123.

Comment: Concat is new in the next version of SQL Server (Denali) which I'm guessing isn't what the OP is using

Comment: @user7,It's just an example of how to combine fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT name, Concat(adress1, adress2) AS columnz FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`select name, convert(varchar, adress1) + convert(varchar, adress2) as columnz from table1;`